# MySQL - Update with CHAR_LENGTH condition

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have thousands of rows that contain a `zipcode` attribute with four integers in.
Some rows contain five integers, and some other contain two, or three integers.

What I want to do is to add a 0 before **rows that contain only four integers**.
The tablename is `zipcode` and the attribute too.

**I want to update the rows and not show them !**

I tried this code with no luck (no row affected) :

```
UPDATE zipcode
SET zipcode = CONCAT('0', zipcode)
WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(zipcode) = 4
```

Btw, I can use CHAR_LENGTH in a simple select, and it works :

```
SELECT *
FROM zipcode
WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(zipcode) = 4
```

So, seems that the `CHAR_LENGTH` doesn't work in my `WHERE` clause.

EDIT: `zipcode` is an int.

Comment: did you get this result from phpmyadmin? Sometimes it says 0 results but the rows actually got updated. Check the datas after commit...

Comment: Yes, I got it from phpmyadmin, but after checking, rows are not updated..

Comment: what is datatype of `zipcode`??

Comment: Please see the edit, `zipcode` is an int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are storing the zipcode as an int, but you really want to treat it as a char.

In that case you have a couple of options:

1) Change the datatype of the column and then execute your update to left pad with 0:

```
alter table zipcode
  modify column zipcode char(5) not null;

update zipcode
set zipcode = lpad(zipcode,5,'0')
where char_length(zipcode) < 5;
```

2) Leave the datatype as is, and just format the data on retrieval by left-padding with 0 in the select statement:

```
select lpad(zipcode,5,'0')
from zipcode;
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30c4f/3)

Comment: I can't change the type of the `zipcode` column.. And I can't use `lpad` function, because some rows contain only two or three numbers.. :/

Comment: lpad() will work with any number of digits under 5. Try it out. It will work for you.

Comment: I can't.. When I said I have some rows which contain only two or three numbers, I mean I DON'T WANT to update these rows.. I just want to update rows which contain 4 numbers only.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the datatype of variable `zipcode` is INT and you want to display all zipcode in 5 digit format. To do that use below.

```
SELECT zipcode as Actual, 
       CASE CHAR_LENGTH(zipcode)
       WHEN 1 THEN CONCAT('0000', zipcode)
       WHEN 2 THEN CONCAT('000', zipcode)
       WHEN 3 THEN CONCAT('00', zipcode)
       WHEN 4 THEN CONCAT('0', zipcode)

       END AS "Final"
FROM zipcode
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30c4f/1)

Comment: That will work, but using lpad() is simpler: `SELECT zipcode as Actual, lpad(zipcode,5,'0') AS "Final" FROM zipcode`

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll try it tomorrow ! And I'll only use your `WHEN 4 ...` line because, like I said in my first post, I only want to update zipcodes with 4 chars only.

Comment: if zipcode is of INT, then you can't... you will need to update table and make zipcode variable as varchar and then update as per @IkeWalker  answer... Please follow IkeWalker answer...